# Netty: Number of outstanding requests

Tags: netty

In apache, there is server-status page which tells me the current status of the server. In particular, it tells me the number of requests currently ('currently' as in, at the time when the server-status page is accessed) being processed. Is there some way to find out the same in Netty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built in, but conceptually it is easy to implement (or easy to describe, anyways ;) )

1. Create a Sharable ChannelHandler:

   - Implements [ChannelUpstreamHandler](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelUpstreamHandler.html)
   - Implements [ChannelDownstreamHandler](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelDownstreamHandler.html)
   - Add an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) field *inFlightRequests* which is incremented on up, and decremented on down.
   - Expose the *inFlightRequests* through JMX so you can monitor the value.
   - You should also decrement *inFlightRequests* in a  [SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exeptionCaught](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.html#exceptionCaught%28org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent%29) callback.  You might want to add an *errors* counter like the *inFlightRequests* counter which is incremented on caught exceptions.
2. Add the [same] ChannelHandler instance to all created pipelines as the first handler.